# Django REST Framework: JSON response to show the ForeignKey values once (Stop repeating)

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

My current response which lists all fields in my serialiser is as follows:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "conversation_id": 1,
            "owner": true,
            "sender": 2,
            "body": "Hello There"
        },
        {
            "conversation_id": 1,
            "owner": true,
            "sender": 2,
            "body": "Second message"
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead, since `conversation_id`, and `owner` are repeated, I would like to take them outside the main response. I **want to return**:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
      "owner": True,
      "conversation_id":1,
      "messages": {
        {
            "sender": 2,
            "body": "Hello There"
        },
        {
            "sender": 2,
            "body": "Second Message"
        },
      },
    ]
}
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='sender.id')
    conversation_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_conversation_id(self, obj):
        conversation = Conversation.objects.filter(message=obj)[0]
        return conversation.id

    def get_owner(self, obj):
        owner = #code to get owner object, the person who started the conversation
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if owner == user:
            return True
        else:
            return False 



    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['conversation_id','sender','body','owner']
```

---

What I tried:

I tried creating another field called messages using

```
messages = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

And using the following function,

```
def get_messages(self, obj):
        return dict(body=obj.body, sender=obj.sender.id)
```

But this doesn't work as I expected, since it only does it for individual listings. So this would work for details, but not for the List type.

Comment: what if `task_id` has different values ? There is a possibility to get different values of `task_id` because you are filtering with `obj`.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta `task_id` has the same value for fixed `conversation_id`, which is provided in the URL. `conversation` has a ForeignKey(Task), and Message has a ForeignKey(Message).

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta A task will have multiple conversations, but each conversation will only have 1 task. Hence if I would like to load messages of a specific conversation, these messages belong to the same task.

Comment: show your models please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't edit your serializer class instead you have to override `get_paginated_response` method on your api view class.

For example:

```
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    response = super().get_paginated_response(data)
    # insert any custom data you want
    conversation = # code to get conversation
    response.data['conversation_id'] = conversation.id
    owner = #code to get owner object
    response.data['owner'] = owner
    return response
```

PS: your 'I want to retun' json is incorrect.

Comment: I get the following error : `/rest_framework/pagination.py:208: UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'api.models.Message'> QuerySet.
`

Comment: I have `owner = User.objects.filter(connected_models__conversation=conversation)[0]` followed by an if statement to set owner to true/false
        `if self.request.user == owner:`

Comment: you have to specify a default ordering for pagination to work. specify ordering = ('field_name',) on your api view class. Copy paste your view class.

Comment: Thanks, added `ordering =('id',)` and it works as expected! I can't reward the bounty just yet